# How to query distict row with the same label from different linestring with multiple segment?

Tags: postgis, sql

I have a multilinestring street table in postgis with two columns: label and prefix. 
This table has 2 different roads with the same name and each road contains multiple segments. 
Roads were splitted on each intersection during authoring in QGIS so that the table has total 14 rows. How to query the two so that i have two unique street rows with prefix and label column in the result?

Comment: not sure how in qgis, you are wanting distinct query.

Comment: hi brad, i meant in sql. not spesific to qgis

Answer (score 1):

If you mean purely sql, the select distinct I think is what you are asking about.
There is a [tutorial here](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/)